# infinite number of maximally unbalanced red black trees

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

I have to find a family of maximally unbalanced red-black trees and to prove the "respective attributes" of that family to prove that there is an infinitely big family of red black trees that have a height close to 2log(n+1).

Now my guess is that this family consists of basically all the red black trees that have one path with s-r-s-r ... nodes and the rest filled with black nodes. But how do I prove this? and how do i formally write down how such a family looks like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Now my guess is that this family consists of basically all the red black trees that have one path with s-r-s-r ... nodes and the rest filled with black nodes.

That's a reasonable guess.

> But how do I prove this?

Describe an infinite sequence of trees T_0, T_1, T_2, T_3, ..., such that, for every integer n, there exists a tree in the sequence with at least n nodes. Show that there exists a constant C such that, for every i, the height of T_i is at least 2log(n_i+1) - C, where n_i is the number of nodes in T_i. (This is one possible interpretation of the ambiguous term "close to".)

> how do i formally write down how such a family looks like?

Inductively. I'll do the all-black trees as an example. The tree T_0 is empty (base case). For all integers i > 0, the tree T_i consists of a black node with left and right subtrees equal to T_{i-1} (inductive step). Then you can prove facts about these trees using induction.

Comment: Well, obviously I have to insert something to get these 2log(n+1) rbtrees and to think about which numbers i have to insert to get the maxrbtree - then generalize the result and that's the proof? how can that be?